# Adjust width of long table in landscape to fit in page

Tags: longtable, circuitikz, adjustwidth

I have been making an assignment for my class in landscape form using long table. It is turning to be larger than the page, so I used the adjustwidth package to move the margins, but it only moves the long table on the last page as shown.

[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,caption,chngpage,pdflscape,amsmath,circuitikz,longtable,lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC,fit}

\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}


\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{-1.5in}
    \setlength\LTleft{1pt}
    \setlength\LTright{1pt}
    \setlength{\LTpre}{1pt}
    \setlength{\LTpost}{1pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}c|c|c|c|c@{}}
        %\caption{Different Amplifiers}
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
        \def\arraystretch{1.25}
            S.No. & Configuration & Circuit Diagram & Output Equation & Applications
            \\ \hline
            1 & Differential Amplifier &
            \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw 
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$} 
            (opamp.-) node[left] {} to [open,v<=$v_{id}$]
            (opamp.+) node[left] {}
            (opamp.out) node[right] {}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.-) to [short] ++(-2.5,0) to [short] ++(0,-1) to [R=$R_{in_2}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in_2}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.+) to [short] ++(-0.5,0) to [R=$R_{in_1}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in_1}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-1) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-2.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$}
            ;
            \addvmargin{1mm}
            \end{tikzpicture} & $\begin{aligned}[t]
                v_{out}&=A*(v_{id})\\ v_{id}&= v_+ - v_-
            \end{aligned}$ & \lipsum[1]\\
            \hline
            2 & Inverting Amplifier & 
            \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.-) --++(-2.5,0) --++(0,-1) to node[ground]  {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.+) --++(-0.5,0) to [R=$R_{in}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-1) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-2.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) to[open] ++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture} &$v_{out} \approx -A*v_{in}$ & \lipsum[1] \\ \hline
            3 & Non-Inverting Amplifier & 
            \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.+) --++(-0.5,0) --++(0,-1) to node[ground]  {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.-) --++(-2.5,0) to [R=$R_{in}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-0.5) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-1.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) to[open] ++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture} & $v_{out} \approx A*v_{in}$ & \lipsum[1] \\

        \end{longtable}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{center}
    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the unindented code.
I just want to know how to make the Table fit the page.
Also could tell me how to put the circuits in another file and include them in the text. Thanks in advance.

Comment: see any latex tutorial, this is unrelated to `longtable`  `c` columns are single line, you want at least the last column to have linebreaking so make it `p{3cm}` or whatever width you want.

Comment: never put `longtable` in a `center` environment` it doesn't centre it it just adds spurious vertical space

Comment: That stopped the table from going out of bounds but there is still that hideous space to its left. What can I do about that?

Comment: remove all these lines that are just breaking longtable and doing nothing useful! `\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{-1.5in}
    \setlength\LTleft{1pt}
    \setlength\LTright{1pt}
    \setlength{\LTpre}{1pt}
    \setlength{\LTpost}{1pt}`

Comment: And what is with the \extracolsep{\fill} if not to create a hideous space to the left?

Comment: I removed both of them, but it is still there.

Comment: It currently looks something like this - [Amplifiers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1VwWvjAM-ryaWw5bFFhbmZ6b1E). I would prefer a near zero margin on both sides of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the settings that are forcing bad spacing and allowing linebreaking in the last column:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,caption,chngpage,pdflscape,amsmath,circuitikz,longtable,
lipsum,array}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC,fit}

\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}


\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \begin{landscape}

%if you want these they need to be here not inside the table
%%        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
%%        \def\arraystretch{1.25}

    \begin{longtable}{@{}c|c|c|c|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.2cm}@{}}
        %\caption{Different Amplifiers}
            S.No. & Configuration & Circuit Diagram & Output Equation & Applications
            \\ \hline
            1 & Differential Amplifier &
            \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw 
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$} 
            (opamp.-) node[left] {} to [open,v<=$v_{id}$]
            (opamp.+) node[left] {}
            (opamp.out) node[right] {}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.-) to [short] ++(-2.5,0) to [short] ++(0,-1) to [R=$R_{in_2}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in_2}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.+) to [short] ++(-0.5,0) to [R=$R_{in_1}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in_1}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-1) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-2.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$}
            ;
            \addvmargin{1mm}
            \end{tikzpicture} & $\begin{aligned}[t]
                v_{out}&=A*(v_{id})\\ v_{id}&= v_+ - v_-
            \end{aligned}$ & \lipsum[1]\\
            \hline
            2 & Inverting Amplifier & 
            \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.-) --++(-2.5,0) --++(0,-1) to node[ground]  {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.+) --++(-0.5,0) to [R=$R_{in}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-1) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-2.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) to[open] ++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture} &$v_{out} \approx -A*v_{in}$ & \lipsum[1] \\ \hline
            3 & Non-Inverting Amplifier & 
            \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.+) --++(-0.5,0) --++(0,-1) to node[ground]  {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.-) --++(-2.5,0) to [R=$R_{in}$] 
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_{in}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-0.5) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-1.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) to[open] ++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture} & $v_{out} \approx A*v_{in}$ & \lipsum[1] \\

        \end{longtable}

    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is still some white space left. I want there to be nearly zero whitespace on both the sides

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka make the `p` column wider (if you make it much wider you get a warning that it is too wide)

Comment: It only moved to the Right. I want nearly no margin on both sides. It currently looks something like this - [Amplifiers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1VwWvjAM-ryaWw5bFFhbmZ6b1E).

Comment: @PrateekDhanuka landscape rotates the text block without changing its size so the horizontal width is the previous textheight, leaving space for the page head and foot. If you want to over-print the page foot area set `\LTleft` to something negative say -2cm  and then you can increase the width of the `p` column. (don't change `\LTright`)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's something like this that you want, removing the white space at the top of cells with a `\raisebox`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz, caption, changepage, pdflscape, array, amsmath, circuitikz, longtable, lipsum}

\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US,circuits.logic.IEC,fit}

\newcommand\addvmargin[1]{
  \node[fit=(current bounding box),inner ysep=#1,inner xsep=0]{};
}


\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{gobble}

 \begin{landscape}
    \begin{center}\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5in}{-1.5in}
    \setlength\LTleft{1pt}
    \setlength\LTright{1pt}
    \setlength{\LTpre}{1pt}
    \setlength{\LTpost}{1pt}
    \begin{longtable}{c|c|c|c| >{\arraybackslash}p{6.5cm}@{}}
        %\caption{Different Amplifiers}
        %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5mm}
        %\def\arraystretch{1.25}
            S.No. & Configuration & Circuit Diagram & Output Equation & Applications
            \\ \hline
            1 & Differential Amplifier &
            \raisebox{\dimexpr2ex-\height}{\begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.-) node[left] {} to [open,v<=$v_\mathrm{id}$]
            (opamp.+) node[left] {}
            (opamp.out) node[right] {}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.-) to [short] ++(-2.5,0) to [short] ++(0,-1) to [R=$R_\mathrm{in_2}$]
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_\mathrm{in_2}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.+) to [short] ++(-0.5,0) to [R=$R_\mathrm{in_1}$]
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_\mathrm{in_1}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-1) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-2.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_\text{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture}} & $\begin{aligned}[t]
                v_\text{out}&=A*(v_\text{id})\\ v_\text{id}&= v_+ - v_-
            \end{aligned}$ & \lipsum[1]%
            \\
            \hline
            2 & Inverting Amplifier &
           \raisebox{\dimexpr2ex-\height}{ \begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.-) --++(-2.5,0) --++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.+) --++(-0.5,0) to [R=$R_{in}$]
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_text{in}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-1) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-2.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) to[open] ++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_text{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture}} &$v_\text{out} \approx -A*v_\text{in}$ & \lipsum[1]%
            \\ \hline
            3 & Non-Inverting Amplifier &
            \raisebox{\dimexpr2ex-\height}{\begin{tikzpicture} [transform shape,baseline=0,scale=0.75] \draw
            (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp) {$A$}
            (opamp.up) --++ (0,0.5) node[vcc] {$+V_{cc}$}
            (opamp.down) --++ (0,-0.5) node[vee] {$-V_{ee}$}
            (opamp.+) --++(-0.5,0) --++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.-) --++(-2.5,0) to [R=$R_{in}$]
            ++(0,-2) to [sV=$V_\text{in}$] ++(0,-1) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) --++(1,0) --++(0,-0.5) to [R=$R_l$]
            ++(0,-1.5) to node[ground] {} ++(0,-0.5)
            (opamp.out) to[open] ++(1,0) to[short,-o] ++(0.5,0) node[]{} node[right]{$v_\text{out}$}
            ;
            \end{tikzpicture}} & $v_\text{out} \approx A*v_\text{in}$ & \lipsum[1]%
        \end{longtable}
    \end{adjustwidth}
    \end{center}
  \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]